# What did the man take from Grey’s ear?

Tags: upgrade-2018

In *Upgrade (2018)*, Grey visited The Old Bones and asked the people about the man
who killed his wife. One man approached him and took something
from Grey’s ear:

[image]

What did the man take from Grey’s ear?

Comment: An earpiece? "*Another interesting tidbit: I didn’t actually add Simon’s voice later – it was all done live on set. Basically, Logan actually had an earpiece in his ear, which I turned into a prop in the movie. Everybody has these phone earpieces; well, the one that Logan had actually worked. We would put Simon in the other room, just out of view, and they would actually talk.*" - https://thespool.net/reviews/movies/2018/05/leigh-whannell-interview/

Comment: Implanted earphones are a pretty big deal in the script; https://www.scriptslug.com/assets/uploads/scripts/upgrade-2018.pdf